# How do I deploy my app to a folder underneath a website

Tags: iis, deployment, msdeploy

I have a deployment script to deploy an application to a website called admintools3t. After the deployment, I see the folders for the app directly underneath that website (when viewed in IIS). The code is deployed to the folder D:\applications\admintools\admintools_wwwroot\myapp1, which is where I (think?) want the code. However, my website is the generic site that needs to host multiple applications, myapp1, myapp2, myapp3, myapp4.

Here is the call I make to use msdeploy to perform the deployment:
call D:\temp\AdminTools\%APP%\%APP%.deploy.cmd /Y "-setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='admintools3t'"

I'm doing this on-the-fly switch on the value because I have multiple environments where I will be deploying to and rather than having multiple profiles, I do this on-the-fly switch, which appears to be working.

How can I tweak this command or add additional parameters so when I view the website in IIS that I see a myapp1 underneath admintools3t?

Comment: I was able to execute the following command and now see my app folder(s) underneath the website (admintools3t): "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy" -verb:sync -source:iisapp=D:\applications\admintools\admintools_wwwroot\studentloanadmin -dest:iisapp="admintools3t\StudentLoanAdmin". I can explore these folders using IIS and can see my pages here: StudentLoanAdmin/content/c_c/builds/4987_admintools_.net_build_automation_project/4987_admintools_72/workspace/studentloanadminobj/debug/package/packagetemp/. See next comment...

Comment: However when I try executing a specific page using http://localhost:85/admintools3t/StudentLoanAdmin/content/c_c/builds/4987_admintools_.net_build_automation_project/4987_admintools_72/workspace/studentloanadminobj/debug/package/packagetemp/login.cshtml, I get the error: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.